# Error connection schema workbench pentaho

Tags: oracle, connection, pentaho, workbench

Good afternoon,
When in the datasource I create a query sql query over sqljdbc, it works correctly and shows results. Now I want to create a schema in the workbench but when I create the connection I get the following error:

> Error connecting to database [test]:
>   org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
>    Error occurred
>   while trying to connect to the database
>   Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
>   Listener refused the connection with the following error:
>   ORA-12505, TNS: listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
>   The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
>   oracle_xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx:1521:xxx.xxx

Comment: Y look the error. i put the string like this oracle_xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx:1521/xxx.xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update the JDBC driver according to your Oracle DB version , there was an issue with the Driver.